# Rails 3. How can I display the contents of the form submission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Just like in PHP you can do `echo $_POST`, how can I display what was submitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails is using params array for request parameters http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6371-action-controller-parameters

Answer (score 1):

It is a hash called `params`.  You can find it at the development.log.